# Windows 10 Computer suddenly off?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, power-supply, gpu

A few days ago i upgrade my pc  ***power supply*** and ***gpu***. But i think its windows issue when my pc is free means (only few program run like **browser** and few **folders**) it suddenly off and turn back on.When i play heavy games like **assassins creed**,**fortnite** e.t.c.Its working properly.

I all ready check my *cpu* **PASTE** its fine.

**Any solution**?

Comment: What does the event log say? An unexpected shutdown never goes without a crash report written in the event log. If it generated a memory dump, that dump will tell you what crashed. If there is no entry in the log, then the system lost power, which may indicate an actual problem with this new PSU.

Comment: I think the PSU may not be supplying enough current and the CPU may not receive enough when it needs to, but games and heavy programs may require a higher power draw which kicks the PSU into supplying a lot more power than is needed, allowing for a lot of leeway in power draw. I would say the PSU is temperamental and you should try another one in case it is faulty. If the problem disappears, then RMA the power supply as it is faulty.

Comment: Thanks  for your information I will try another psu very soon